# does matlab cache solutions for eigs

Tags: performance, matlab, caching, eigenvector

I seem to be getting different performance results when using `eigs`. On the same matrix, calling
`[c, v] = eigs(A, 2, 'sm');`
somtimes takes 30 seconds and sometimes 2 seconds. 

I need to know whether there's a speedup using some caching on subsequent calls for `eigs` on the same matrix since I need to report the times...

Comment: Really? 30 seconds? How big is this matrix? Maybe you're running something in the process that takes up a lot of CPU?

Answer (score 1):

If so, this doesn't appear to be a generic feature.  I ran this test from the command line

```
A = randn(10000); 
B = randn(10000); 
C = B; 
tic; [c1,v1] = eigs(A,2,'sm'); toc; 
tic; [c2,v2] = eigs(A,2,'sm'); toc; 
tic; [c3,v3] = eigs(B,2,'sm'); toc; 
tic; [c4,v4] = eigs(C,2,'sm'); toc
```

and got this result

> Elapsed time is 32.373128 seconds.
>
> Elapsed time is 28.412905 seconds.
>
> Elapsed time is 32.752616 seconds.
>
> Elapsed time is 29.024055 seconds.

I'm surprised, because usually MATLAB tries to outsmart you and will store results for reuse.

Comment: This would be a bad thing IF MATLAB tried to circumvent repeated calls, by simply returning the last thing it did. What if your function is a random process? Would you want MATLAB to return the same result? For example, should repeated calls to rand return the same result? Of course not. But in fact, eigs uses a random starting value, so it COULD generate different results down at the least significant bit. Or, it might return the same set of eigenvectors, but with a different sign.

Comment: @woodchips: MATLAB is a scripted language.  The interpreter can often determine whether a repeated function call will return the same value, especially with built-in functions.  It may be, as you say, that MATLAB knows eigs uses a call to rand and so should begin from scratch each time.

Comment: Sorry, but I know for a fact that MATLAB does NOT do as you say, and I can prove that to be a true statement. It has never been true since version 3.2 (as far back as I go as a heavy user, though I had a copy of an earlier version) and it is still not true in the most recent release.

Comment: @woodchips: I stand corrected.  I can't find any documentation that says the interpreter reuses intermediate results. I swear I've seen the second call to a function return much faster, but maybe that's in my head.

Answer (score 0):

Under some circumstances, a large enough matrix might push things into virtual memory, or not, depending upon whether there is a large enough block of contiguous RAM available. Or, you may be doing something on the side.

You can verify what is happening by watching a process monitor as you do the test. Are there suddenly large amounts of disk accesses? If so, then virtual memory is being touched. Is there a different, unrelated process active that is hogging the CPU?